# Google Maps API - Slow Max Zoom Service

Tags: google-maps

I am using Max Zoom Service of Google Maps API to get the maximum zoom level of a given coordinates. Most of the time it is fast and each request only takes around 150 ms. However, there have been a few occasions that the service became extremely slow, around 20 seconds.

```
maxZoomService = new google.maps.MaxZoomService();
maxZoomService.getMaxZoomAtLatLng(center, function(response) {

// my process

});
```

Have you experienced similar issue?

Comment: see my solution for this issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/36591458/3413103

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have experienced the same problems. 
We're using wkhtmltoimage to generate map images for inclusion into PDF files using wkhtmltopdf.
We have to set a maximum time in which the image is generated. If it's too short, then you often will not have all the map tiles downloaded in order to create the image. Too long and there's a really noticeable delay for users (with our comnection 5 seconds seems optimal)
We wanted to make sure that generated satellite maps do not exceed the maximum zoom level using the MaxZoomService and that's when we ran into problems with the service.

As it is an asynchronous service, ideally we wait for the service to report the max zoom level BEFORE creating the map and therefore triggering the correct .map tile downloads.

Setting a default "fallback" zoom for the map in case the service is being really slow is not really an option as subsequently updating the zoom level when getting a return value from the service will in most cases cause new tiles to be reloaded, requiring more delay...

If like us you're interested in specific, repeatable locations (e.g. from a database) then one option might be to cache (store) the max zoom levels in advance and periodically check for updated values.

In our specific case the only other option would be to allow the service a specific amount of time (say 2 seconds) and if it does not respond then fall back to a default zoom.

Not ideal, but can handle the services' "Bad hair days"...