# Constant error return on google maps maxZoomService.getMaxZoomAtLatLng()

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm experiencing a big problem with googles `maxZoomService.getMaxZoomAtLatLng`, since it absolutely random decides to return error state, sometimes 10 times in a row, sometimes it works, but I can't figure out why the zoom sometimes just fails.

I tried to solve it by retrying the request multiple times, but it seems like that if I get an error on the first request I'll get the error for all retries too. At the same time I'm facing an issue that got listed in another [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14392645) but this isn't my main problem, it just occurs too.

Following my example code:

```
setMap : function() {
    wirkonf.frontend.triggerLoadAnim();
    wirkonf.storage.mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(wirkonf.storage.geoCoords.lat, wirkonf.storage.geoCoords.lng),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    };
    wirkonf.storage.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmc'),
    wirkonf.storage.mapOptions);
    wirkonf.storage.map.setTilt(0);
    var maxZoomService = new google.maps.MaxZoomService();
    maxZoomService.getMaxZoomAtLatLng(wirkonf.storage.mapOptions.center,
        function(response){
            wirkonf.storage.mapZoomMax = response.zoom;
            var ret;
            if (response.zoom > 20) {
                ret = 20;
            } else {
                ret = response.zoom;
            }
            wirkonf.storage.mapZoomCurr = ret;
            wirkonf.storage.map.setZoom(ret);
        }
    );
},
```

So my question is, has anyone else experienced this problem or maybe even knows a good workaround to solve it?

Comment: The [MaxZoomService works as expected for me](http://jsfiddle.net/kuv64vcn/1/), can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I am experiencing similar behavior. I'd be happy to piece together something MCTR if I can't get to the bottom of this by tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, but noticed that the actual GET request actually return with a valid json response "{zoom:19}" but for some reason got converted into an error inside the google maps js code.

I then tried to simply bypass the google javascript and hit the service directly:

```
var myMap = {
    maxZoomServiceCallback: function(resp) {
        gmap.setZoom(resp.zoom);
    },
    isAerialAvailable: function() {
        var ll = gmap.getCenter();
        var proj = gmap.getProjection();
        if(!proj) {
            setTimeout(function(){myMap.isAerialAvailable();},100);
            return;
        }   
        var p = proj.fromLatLngToPoint(new google.maps.LatLng(ll.lat, ll.lon));
        p.x=Math.floor(p.x / 256 * 8388608);
        p.y=Math.floor(p.y / 256 * 8388608);
        jQuery.getScript("https://khm.googleapis.com/mz?v=199&x="+p.x+"&y="+p.y+"&z=23&token=0&callback=myMap.maxZoomServiceCallback");
        //maxZoomService.getMaxZoomAtLatLng({lng: ll.lon, lat: ll.lat}, this.maxZoomServiceCallback)
    }
}
```

After I got this code with the undefined/null check for gmap.getProjection() to work, I assumed that the projection being null could be the same reason  the maxZoomService kept failing (probably caused by some underlying timing issue), I then tried the maxZoomService again, but keeping the undefined check. This time it worked. Please try it out for yourselves but it works me for now.

Edit 14/4: I have since removed `maxZoomService.getMaxZoomAtLatLng` again and gone back to my custom `jQuery.getScript` call as this worked consistently.

Update 5/5/2016: Google seems to have made some changes and release a new API version. I am getting better results with:

jQuery.getScript("https://khm.googleapis.com/mz?**v=203**&x="+p.x+"&y="+p.y+"&z=23&token=0&callback=myMap.maxZoomServiceCallback"